# Serial port data corrupted when sending a specific pattern of bytes

Tags: c++, pyserial, uart, crc32

I have a python script that sends a stream of data, and then I have a Linux embedded computer receiving the data (code written in C++). Most of the times it works, however, I am noticing I get data corrupted when sending **specific patterns of bytes**. I have been struggling with this for a while and I don't know how to solve it.

Python script (sender):

```
serial = serial.Serial("COM2", 115200, timeout=5)
all_bytes = [0x63,0x20,0x72,0x69,0x67,0x68,0x74,0x73,0x20,0x61,0x6e,0x64,0x20,0x72,0x65,0x73,0x74,0x72,0x69,0x63,0x74,0x69,0x6f,0x6e,0x73,0x20,0x69,0x6e,0x0a,0x68,0x6f,0x77,0xff,0x20,0xf0,0x8b]

fmt = "B"*len(all_bytes)

byte_array = struct.pack(fmt,*all_bytes)

serial.write(byte_array)
```

C++ code (receiver)

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> ustring; // ustring = vector containing a bunch of uint8_t elements

// configure the port
int UART::configure_port()      
{
    struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in

    cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B115200);    // set baud rates
    cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B115200);

    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;
    port_settings.c_cflag |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    port_settings.c_cc[VTIME]     =   10;                  // n seconds read timeout
    //port_settings.c_cc[VMIN]      =   0;     // blocking read until 1 character arrives 
    port_settings.c_iflag     &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl
    port_settings.c_lflag     &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
    port_settings.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;              // make raw

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
    return(fd);
} 

int UART::uart_read(ustring *data,int buffer_size)
{
    // Buffer
    uint8_t * buf = new uint8_t[buffer_size];

    // Flush contents of the serial port
    //tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    //usleep(1000);

    ustring data_received;
    // Read
    int n_bytes = 0;

    while (n_bytes < buffer_size)
    {
        int n = read( fd, buf , buffer_size );

        // Some bytes were read!
        if (n > 0)
        {
             n_bytes+=n;

             // Add to buffer new data!
             for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
             {
                data_received.push_back(buf[i]);
             }
        }


    }


    // String received
    *data = data_received;
    cout << "Data received..." << endl;
    print_ustring(data_received);




    delete[] buf;

    return read_valid;

}


int main()
{ 
    UART uart_connection;

    vector<uint8_t> data;
    vector<uint8_t> *data_ptr = &data;
    int status = uart_connection.uart_read(data_ptr,36);


    return 0;
}
```

This is what's happening:

If I send the following bytes (from python):

```
0x632072696768747320616e64207265737472696374696f6e7320696e0a686f77ff20f08b
```

This is what I am receiving (in C++ program):

```
0x632072696768747320616e64207265737472696374696f6e7320696e0a686f77ffff20f0
```

As you can see there are a few bytes at the end (the CRC) that are changed, the rest seems fine. But it doesn't always happen, it only happens when sending some specific pattern of bytes.

Let's say I send the following for instance (some other pattern):

```
0x6868686868686868686868686868686868686868686868686868686868686868b18cf5b2
```

I get exactly what I am sending in the above pattern!

Do you think it might be Pyserial changing my unsigned bytes to ASCII? I have no clue what's going on. I have been struggling with this for days!

*EDIT*

For anyone interested, apparently the problem was that struct termios needs to be initialized right after declaring it.

Here is the code that solved it:

```
// configure the port
int UART::configure_port()      
{
    struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in
    tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings);
    // Open ttys4
    fd = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );

    if(fd == -1) // if open is unsucessful
    {
        //perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
        printf("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS4. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        /* get the current options */
        printf("port is open.\n");


        cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);    // set baud rates
        cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);

        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   //Stop bits = 1 
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    // clear mask
        port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;       // data bits = 8
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;   // Turn off hardware flow control
        port_settings.c_cflag |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

        port_settings.c_cc[VMIN]      =   0;     // blocking read until 1 character arrives 
        // port_settings.c_cc[VTIME]     =   10;                  // n seconds read timeout

        port_settings.c_iflag     &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl
        port_settings.c_lflag     &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw -- NON Cannonical mode
        // port_settings.c_iflag |= IGNPAR; // Input parity options
        // port_settings.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;              // make raw

        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
    }
    return(fd);
}
```

Comment: So I know for sure now that pyserial is not the problem. I tried replacing pyserial with nodejs serial port library. The same problem persists. I noted that the only way to "fix it" is closing the port and opening it again. Once the port is opened, the serial port data will either be (always corrupted or always right) depending if the first one was received OK or corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program fails to properly perform termios initialization.
1. The `struct termios port_settings` needs to be initialized by calling **tcgetattr()** before any modifications.
2. Since you've configured non-canonical mode, the VMIN needs to be defined.  For whatever reason you have the statement commented out.

> As you can see there are a few bytes at the end (the CRC) that are changed,...

Looks like an input byte with value 0xFF was duplicated.
This will occur when PARMRK and INPCK are set and IGNPAR is not set.
Per the termios man page:

```
PARMRK  If  this  bit  is  set,  input bytes with parity or framing errors are marked when passed to the program. 
        ...  
        Therefore, a valid byte \377 is passed to the program as two bytes, \377 \377, in this case.
```

Since your termios structure is never properly initialized, these settings are possibly configured for your program.

---

**ADDENDUM**

> So I called "tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings);" RIGHT AFTER declaring it, and RIGHT BEFORE opening the port.

No, despite any positive results that is illogical code.
The file descriptor is not valid, and if the return code were checked (as all system calls should be), you would realize that **tcgetattr()** failed.

The macro **cfmakeraw()** is the guide that indicates the salient values for proper termios configuration for non-canonical mode:

```
       termios_p->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
       termios_p->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
       termios_p->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);

       termios_p->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
       termios_p->c_cflag |= CS8;
```

So your program should look like:

```
    ...  
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);
    cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);

    port_settings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);  /* ignore modem controls */
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;           /* 8-bit characters */
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;       /* no parity bit */
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;       /* only need 1 stop bit */
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;  /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
    port_settings.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    port_settings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    port_settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    port_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting....What flags do you recommend? I added: port_settings.c_iflag |= IGNPAR; // Input parity options 

But now I am getting 0xFF replaced with a 0x7F.

I also initialized struct termios with tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings); and added VMIN

Comment: The salient flag is PARMRK, which needs to be cleared.  Before executing your program, do `stty sane -F /dev/tty... ` or reboot.  Normally PARMRK is not set.

Comment: Ok this has been rough but apparently the problem went away... It was not PARMRK, but it was probably related to your first point, struct termios needs to be initialized. So I called "tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings);" RIGHT AFTER declaring it, and RIGHT BEFORE opening the port. 

If I initialize it after opening the port (just like these guys did here: https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) I get that problem and all my oxFF's get duplicated. So it has to be initialized just right after declaring it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuisCruz -- See addendum.

Comment: You are totally right.... I think I have been spending too much time on this that I couldn't even notice that the file descriptor was invalid xD I have no idea why it worked haha But I added those flags off (including PARMRK ) and now it works like a charm. Thank you